# how to use regular expression in web_reg_save_param in VUGen?

Tags: regex, loadrunner

I have a trouble in correlating a Link ID which is some value inside changes from link to link. 
so I need to create a regular expression to handle all of the variable values in the page.

below are the lines of code I use :

```
web_reg_save_param("corr_activitysubcategory", 
    "LB/IC=categorysearchCats_lnkCat_16\" href=\"/category/Search.aspx\?s=&amp;t=4&amp;f=28&amp;v=",
    "RB/IC=&amp;sh=0&amp;", 
    "Ord=all", 
    "Notfound=warning",
    "Search=body", 
    "RelFrameId=1", 
    LAST);
```

the number (16) is varies for each link... so I need to put a regular expression to ignore the number.
I tried put .* instead of 16 but it results in no data matched.

Comment: If you post two possible strings and the value you want to extract it would be easier to help you.

Comment: thanks Buzzy, 
as I mentioned above the 16 number is varies, value are number from (0 to 20) for each link. so i want to replace it with a regular expression pattern which will ignore the number at all. 
I hope you get my want now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
web_reg_save_param("corr_activitysubcategory", 
    "LB/ALNUMIC=categorysearchCats_lnkCat__^\" href=\"/=\"/category/Search.aspx\?s=&amp;t=4&amp;f=28&amp;v=",
    "RB/IC=&amp;sh=0&amp;", 
    "Ord=all", 
    "Notfound=warning",
    "Search=body", 
    "RelFrameId=1", 
    LAST);
```

the issue solved using "LB/ALNUMIC" tag, which accepts regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

categorysearchCats_lnkCat_[0-9]+\" href=\"/category/Search.aspx